# alter session for current schema

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Suppose their are two database environment (prod legacy and prd exadata). I am the user and have select privilege on both db having same schema name A.

My current session is "prod legacy"

If I run `alter session set current_schema = A;`

Which schema I am accessing: legacy or exadata? Why?

Also, I have access to schema B.

If i run `alter session set current_schema = B;`

Why am I able to access schema B based on A's schema configuration.

Note: I am using SQL Developer

Comment: `alter session` does **not** change the connection to a different database. It only changes the default schema for unqualified objects. It will never change to a different database

Comment: Thanks, i need more explanation as I am new to oracle..what is unqualified object? Also, why i am able to access schema B database, even though its altogether different configuration?

Comment: `select * from tbl` is unqualified. `select * from A.tbl` is qualified.  Notice that the latter prefixes the table name with the schema name.  When you use the `alter session set current_schema XX` command, all you're doing is telling Oracle which schema to use when you don't qualify an object name.  So `select * from tbl` could query `A.tbl` or `B.tbl` depending on which schema is set as the *current* schema. But none of this has anything to do with which database you are using. That is determined at connection time and can't be changed.

Comment: @sstan I think you should really post this as an answer... this is not a comment anymore :) (and the right explanation for the OP to understand)

Comment: Thanks both of you,my concept are more clear now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A database is composed of multiple schemas (btw, in Oracle, a schema is is pretty much the same as a user), and each schema can contain different objects, such as tables, views, etc.

Which database you connect to is determined by which connection string you used when establishing a database session, and cannot be changed for the lifetime of that session.

Let's say that in your database, you have 2 schemas (users): `A` and `B`, and they both contain a table called `tbl`.  When you query:

```
select * from tbl
```

...which one does it query? That's where the `current_schema` setting comes in.  By default, it's the schema of the user you connected with.  So if you connected with user `A`, then you'll be querying `A.tbl` by default.

If you instead want to query `B.tbl` while connected as user `A`, you have 2 options:

1. You can always explicitly qualify the table name with the desired schema when writing your query. e.g.: `select * from B.tbl`
2. You can use the `alter session set current_schema = B` command to change the default schema to `B`, so that when you say `select * from tbl`, it will translate it automatically to `select * from B.tbl`.

Also note that, just using the `alter session set current_schema` command doesn't automatically grant you permissions on the objects of that schema. All it does is interpret your queries differently when you don't explicitly qualify the object names. But you need to have been granted the necessary permissions to query those objects successfully.

Comment: Great answer!!Now a little confused about statement.. "Which database you connect to is determined by which connection string you used when establishing a database session, and connect be changed for the lifetime of that session."please elaborate this.When i create a connection in sql developer by putting sid etc., am i connecting to db or schema?Is database and schema can be used interchangeably?Also,is their any command for non-dba to check that a user is having access to which schema?

Comment: No, database != schema.  When you connect using a connection string like `user/password@sid`, you are connecting to a database identified by the `sid`, but logging to that database using a specific user.  When logged in as that user, you can query all the objects of any schema that is part of that database and that you have permissions to. But every user has a *default* schema that it *owns*.

Comment: As for your permissions question, permissions are granted per *object* not per *schema*.  So if schema `B` has 1000 tables, and I want user (schema) `A` to have access to them, I can't simply grant you access to schema `B`.  I have to grant you access to all 1000 tables individually.  As for a command to get that info, I don't remember offhand. You may want to search for it, and ask a new question if you can't find the answer anywhere.